# Ionic2 and SOAP api

Tags: web-services, soap, ionic2

I need to make an integration using "Ionic2" and a SOAP webService! But do not have someone Lib that make this integration.

I try to make it with https://github.com/autopulous/angular2-soap and others, but it's depreciated in some packages, and I can not depreciate the packages because if I make it maybe break my application.

What do?

Comment: I have just upgraded the original angular-soap to make it work with typescript and Ionic2, take a look https://github.com/infoxicator/angular2-soap

Answer (score 0):

I just fix it making a API with python to be my 'conversationalist'. :s